# why isn't my discord bot connecting to the channel with discord.py rewritten?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

OK so i am still pretty new to python and programming in general trying to get my discord bot join my channel but when i type the command its not joining. i have tried several different things. this is the code:

```
@client.event
async def voice_chat(message, VoiceChannel):
    if message.content == "!join":
            musicplayer = VoiceChannel.connect()
```

i also tried to replace both VoiceChannels with client and it still didn't work and i also tried to replace if message.content with await but nothing tried has worked. does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`commands.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands.command)

```
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx, voice_channel):
```

Then use [`voice_channel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect)

```
voice_channel.connect()
```

I suggest using a [`VoiceChannelConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.VoiceChannelConverter) as well. So all in all your function should look somewhat like this minus any other logic you want.

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx, voice_channel: commands.VoiceChannelConverter):
    try:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    except commands.BotMissingPermissions as error:
        #send them a prettied up message saying HEY I NEED {} PERMS!
    await ctx.send(f"I have joined: {voice_channel}")
```

Also note this *should* be within a cog/*extension* so take that into consideration. At least that's normal convention, something like a "voice" cog.